# Pass variable set in PowerShell task to another task (YAML)

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

I have a yaml file with following tasks:

```
parameters:  

 steps:    
- task: AzurePowerShell@4
  displayName: 'script'
  inputs:
        azureSubscription: 
        ScriptPath: 
        ScriptArguments: 
        azurePowerShellVersion: LatestVersion

 - task: AzureResourceGroupDeployment@2
   displayName: 'deployment'
   inputs:
         azureSubscription: 
         resourceGroupName: 
         location: 
         overrideParameters: '-abc $(var1) -def $(var2)'
         deploymentMode: 'Incremental'
```

In the Powershell Script, I'm setting 2 variables as follows:

```
    $ABC = 1
    $DEF = 2
    Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=var1;isOutput=true]$ABC"
    Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=var2;isOutput=true]$DEF"
```

On trying to use these variables in the 2nd task (in overrideParameters section), I see the following error:

### [error]InvalidContentLink: Unable to download deployment content from 'xxxx$(var1)'

### [error]InvalidContentLink: Unable to download deployment content from 'xxxx$(var2)'

Am I setting variables in PowerShell script wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to add a reference name to the first task. For example:

```
- task: AzurePowerShell@4
  displayName: 'script'
  inputs:
        azureSubscription: 
        ScriptPath: 
        ScriptArguments: 
        azurePowerShellVersion: LatestVersion
  name: test
```

Then in the second task, get the variable value in the form of `$(test.var1)`.

This is because in definition editor, downstream tasks won't get variable name intellisense for output variables that were published by an ad-hoc script. You can refer to this [document](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/blob/master/docs/preview/outputvariable.md#for-ad-hoc-script) for details.

In addition, here is a [blog](https://medium.com/microsoftazure/how-to-pass-variables-in-azure-pipelines-yaml-tasks-5c81c5d31763) with some examples on how to pass variables in Azure Pipelines YAML tasks.